# Split package and class logging

Tags: java, log4j

I would like to configure logger for certain class to write to separate file.
But I have the same level for package logger and messages are written twice.

Here is my configuration:

```
<appender name="FILE_TRACE" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="c:/logs/trace.log"/>
    <param name="MaxFileSize" value="100MB"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%X{user} - %X{docbase} - %X{sysObjectId} - %d{ABSOLUTE} [%t] %m%n"/>
    </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="QUERY_TRACE" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="c:/logs/query.log"/>
    <param name="MaxFileSize" value="100MB"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%X{user} - %X{docbase} - %X{sysObjectId} - %d{ABSOLUTE} [%t] %m%n"/>
    </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="stdout" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%d{ISO8601}|%-5p|%-22t|%C|%M|%-4L] %m%n"/>
    </layout>
</appender>

   <logger name="package">
        <level value="DEBUG"/>
        <appender-ref ref="FILE_TRACE"/>
    </logger>

    <logger name="package.MyClass">
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="QUERY_TRACE"/>
    </logger>

    <root>
        <level value="INFO"/>
        <appender-ref ref="stdout"/>
    </root>
```

In MyClass I get the Logger in this way:

```
Logger.getLogger(this);
```

Comment: there was a configuration flag for similar problems, it was named additivity but I've used ages ago.

Comment: Just read about additivity here http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<logger name="package.MyClass" additivity="false">
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="QUERY_TRACE"/>
</logger>
```

And "upper" loggers in hierarchy won't log messages from `package.MyClass`